# Why is CRTP(curiously recursive template pattern) tries to choose another same name function of another private base class?

Tags: c++, crtp

I am learning CRTP(curiously recursive template pattern) in c++.

I made the following code to learn CRTP.

The code just tried to get iterator from a base class through another base class for CRTP.

The problem is gcc compiler cannot select the function, GET_CONTAINRE_ITERATOR_CRTP::begin() in test_get_iterator_by_crtp() below. It seems gcc confuses begin() of GET_CONTAINRE_ITERATOR_CRTP<(int)> and ContainerIterator<(int)> because the error vanishes when I change the name of GET_CONTAINRE_ITERATOR_CRTP<(int)>::begin() to begin_another().

I expected ci.template begin(); below cannot be ContainerIterator::begin() because it is implemented as private base class and we cannot access it directly.

Please someone tell me why the begin() is ambiguous.
If I made an easy mistake or misunderstanding, please forgive me. Thank you very much.

```
template <typename T>
class ContainerIterator : public std::vector<T> {
public:
    auto begin(void) {
        return std::vector<T>::begin();
    }
};

template <typename Derived>
class GET_CONTAINRE_ITERATOR_CRTP {
public:

    template <typename T>
    auto begin(void) {
        Derived* host = static_cast<Derived*>(this);
        // The following line makes a compile error of ambiguous name, begin().
        return host->template ContainerIterator<T>::begin();
    }
};

// CI = Container Iterator
class CI : private ContainerIterator<int>, public GET_CONTAINRE_ITERATOR_CRTP<CI> {
public:
    friend class GET_CONTAINRE_ITERATOR_CRTP<CI>;
};

void test_get_iterator_by_crtp(void) {
    CI ci{};
    auto it = ci.template begin<int>();
}
```

error message :

```
error: request for member ‘begin’ is ambiguous
```

Comment: compiles for me. Apple clang 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)

Comment: @Richard Hodges : thank you for reporting it. My compiler is gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explicitly tell the compiler that base template class will implement method `begin()`. Inside your `CI` class you can do it by adding one `using` instruction to public section:

```
using GET_CONTAINRE_ITERATOR_CRTP<CI>::begin;
```

By default compiler makes fair suggestion that some specializations of `GET_CONTAINRE_ITERATOR_CRTP` temlate can be implemented without `begin()` method.
For futher information you can refer to Item 43 by Scott Meyers ("Effective C++")

**UPD:**
`using GET_CONTAINRE_ITERATOR_CRTP<CI>::begin;` will helps. But main reason for such behavior is in the order in which 'name lookup' and 'access checking' are done by GCC. According to the standard: `The access rules (Clause 11) are considered only once name lookup and function overload resolution (if applicable) have succeeded.` This leads to problem with ambiguous `begin` name. It is not clear while Clang behaves different.

Comment: thank you for solution. I don't have Effective C++ near here. But I will read it later. ... By the way, is this bug of gcc? because Richard Hodges reported that clang does not judge it is an error.

Comment: I think this is a "feature" (error??) of Clang compiler. You can read some additional information here [C++ Faq Lite.](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members)

Comment: thank you for replying. I went book store and read the item 43 and the site you recommended. I think they instruct how to access base class with dependent name. However my question is why gcc try to look up function of a base class which is inherited privately; private ContainerIterator<int>.

Comment: From the standard: `The access rules (Clause 11) are considered only once name lookup and function overload resolution (if
applicable) have succeeded`. So  name lookup  will be done before access checking and will lead to `ambiguous`  error